# Workflow that executes any time a record is changed or page is accessed

Tags: workflow, formula, field-update

I have created a workflow and field update to go with it. I have made the workflow evaluate each time the record is created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria. I have made the criteria a formula that is "1<>0". This does not cause the workflow to run at all. Can someone assist?

I need a workflow that will run every time the page is accessed or anything is changed.

Comment: note that SFDC workflows won't execute on delete/undelete events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set your formula to `TRUE`. Also make sure you have activated said `Workflow`.

Answer (score 4):

Change the Evaluation criteria to "Every time a record is created or edited".  Then just use a formula of `TRUE`.  This will run every time the record is created or edited, no matter what.

**Important to note:** This does NOT run every time the page is accessed as you mention in your question.  WFR's only run on insertion or editing of records.  If you need something to happen every time the page is accesses, then you will need a custom VF page and Apex controller.

Comment: or a custom VF page+controller that is embedded as a component on a standard pagelayout

Comment: Good point.  Yes, that would do it as well.